# Do timing belts have any run-in (break-in) period? Myth or fact?

Tags: timing-belt, break-in

I read in some forums that brand new timing belts have a run-in (break-in, wear-in, etc!) period of about 2000 kms (1200 miles) when they are first installed on the car. It was said that you should not rev your engine more than 3000 RPM in the first 1200 miles to let the belt run in properly. Is this really true? I ask this because I recently replaced my timing belt and revved my engine to about 4000 RPM (once or twice) before reaching 1200 miles! Did I damage the belt?

Comment: Timing belt jobs have no break in period..simple as that..if the job was performed correctly then That's it.done..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a standard replacement timing belt (OEM or direct replacement), there's no such break-in period. You replace and go.

As an aside, there are specific break-in periods/schedules for the engine or cam(s). Taking a cursory glance around the internet, I'm seeing a lot of stuff for breaking in these (yah, that's internet wisdom going on there, too), but ***everything*** I'm seeing about timing belts agrees with me stating there is no break-in period for them. I'm not sure where you're getting your information from, but I'd highly suggest you stay away from said forum, because they really don't know what they're talking about (IMHO).

Comment: My main source is a simple Google search. There were lots of results for " timing belt break-in " and many people had different ideas. I couldn't figure out which one is right.

Comment: If there were such a break-in period for such products, I'd expect the manufacturers to include a note with them explaining their procedure.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - Make sure you are differentiating between ***engine*** break-in and ***timing belt*** break-in. I saw in my Google search there were quite a few references to just engine break-in under my search, which means the two can *easily* be confused. Believe me, there's no break-in period for a standard timing belt. I've never seen one specified anywhere and I've done a LOT of timing belts through the years. They should be considered "done and run".

Comment: @Paulster2 - I definitely believe what you believe about timing belt break-in (which doesn't exist) but you should also believe that I definitely know the difference between engine break-in and timing belt break-in! I definitely didn't confuse the two terms. Since many people had asked about timing belt (not engine) break-in in so many car enthusiast forums, I wanted to make sure if such an idea is really true. I apologize if my question made you sad or unhappy.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - Oh, I'm sorry if it seemed I was belittling you or talking down to you ... that was definitely not my intent. I just brought it up because I almost made that mistake and assumed anyone else could make the same mistake as well.

Comment: @Paulster2 - No problem with that. I always trust you and other members here. That's why I always ask you about anything I suspect. Your words matter a lot to me.

Comment: Hearsay, rumors and old wives tales spread misinformation. Factory service manuals would be the correct source of info instead of Google. The internet is  full of misinformation. I use service manuals and share info when possible. Since I replaced my timing belt (GM vehicle), a lot of parts are removed to replace my timing belt. Fortunately, engineering thought this out and added a spring loaded tensioner among the idler pulleys so the tensioner applies the correct tension throughout the belt's life.